# I have a camera solver on a camera, how can I delete the solver on a duplicate camera and keep the rotation and location the same?

Tags: camera, tracking

I have motion-tracked a scene and have a camera with a camera solver on it. I duplicated the camera and need to delete the camera solver in the second camera. I was wondering how I can delete the camera solver and keep the location and rotation the same as the first camera so I can keyframe it and animate it later in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the tracking information to keyframes.

On the selected camera, open the camera solver constraint and click on convert the constraint to f-curve

[image]

Motion and rotation of the camera will be converted to keyframes.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/motion_tracking/camera_solver.html